# How can I detect a Python installation in WiX and determine the version?

Tags: python, wix

I've already found [this page](http://www.optimalbpm.se/wiki/index.php/Python_packages_from_exe_to_WiX_to_msi#The_.wxs-file), but it is keyed to a particular version of Python both by the compile-time variable `$(var.python_version)` and the compile-time variable `$(var.python_guid)`.

I need to determine if *any* Python installs exist, and potentially what their versions are (in case I have a minimum version requirement, which I'm also not sure how to detect for).

Is there a straight-forward, or any, way to do this?

Comment: Nothing is straightforward in WiX, but you can probably do this using some sort of [DirectorySearch](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directorysearch.html). If all else fails, you can (with some difficulty) retrieve this using a custom action.

Comment: Hi, I wrote the article,  and in my case I am after a specific version to make sure the application works *exactly* as predicted.
I'm afraid that finding *any* version, as there are different packages and locations for Python(other product ids), might be difficult. So it is likely that you miss one. Could you perhaps elaborate on why you need to list them?
If I were you, I'd play it safe and go for a specific version and install it if it's missing, to handle stuff like this like that isn't how I think its done. There is no apt-like mechanism to keep track of versions in windows like that.

Comment: @NicklasBörjesson We have a python package that we are deploying from an installer and would like to register it in the relevant site-packages. As it turns out, not being a python aficionado, I didn't know that there were significant differences between 2.x and 3.x that make our package incompatible with both. Thus, we are now shipping both a 2.x and 3.x version. We have also decided to use the PYTHON_PATH environment variable instead of deploying directly to site-packages. It would be nice to detect the installation of python, though.

Comment: @Veggie: If i were you, I would instead probably try to make the package compatible with both version 2.x and 3.x. It is not that hard, and you simplify development, article here: http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html

But when it comes to Windows deployment, I am leaning more and more towards checking if the python version I am using is installed and if not installing it.
Also, I then use pip custom actions to install dependencies. I don't put stuff manually into site-packages.
My goal, though, is to use GIT to deploy all commercial code, I won't put that in site-packages anyway.

Comment: @Veggie And then I am talking about the *exact* package I want installed. Usually, it is the official package, so problems should not be that common. And, as said before, then I know exactly in which interpreter the system is running. Don't want to take any chances with that, really.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **RegistrySearch**

here is an example code to find matlab installation

```
<util:RegistrySearch Id="MatlabPath" Variable="MatlabPathExists" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MathWorks\MATLAB\4.17" Result="exists" Win64="yes" />
```

for .Net you can give minimum requirement

```
<ExePackage Id="Netfx45Xxx" Cache="no" Name="Files\dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe" Compressed="no" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q" SourceFile="..\SetupProject\dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe" DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;))" InstallCondition="(VersionNT &gt;= v6.0 OR VersionNT64 &gt;= v6.0) AND (NOT (Netfx4FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot; OR Netfx4x64FullVersion=&quot;4.5.50709&quot;))" />
```